# Make a new div element for each element in an array with JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to make a div element for each element in an array using reactjs JSX. I was not sure how to really go about this but I tried doing this:

```
{results.forEach(element => {
               <div className={classes.SearchResults}>

                {results[element]}    

                </div>

})}
```

This didn't work but I am fairly confident that it is something along these lines. I receive no errors results is an array element I defined elsewhere and that is working completely. The only issue is displaying a new div element for each of elements within the results array.
If you need more code I am happy to give you it though I think this should be a sufficient amount.

Comment: It's `map` not `forEach`

Comment: Map would return a new array whereas I am trying to make a new div element for each element in the array. Could you elaborate further why this is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you're using the wrong array method here. `Array.map()` returns a new array, and you can use that to return an array of `divs` to render for each item in the `results` array.

For more details, take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 4):

Close.

First, you want `.map()`, not `.forEach()`.  The latter just iterates but doesn't return anything, whereas the former returns a new array (with the same size as the original) "mapped" to a new element structure (in this case JSX elements).

---

Aside from that... The use of curly braces `{}` here creates a function body, which in this case consists of a JSX element but doesn't return anything:

```
{
  <div className={classes.SearchResults}>
    {results[element]}    
  </div>
}
```

You can return the element explicitly:

```
{
  return (<div className={classes.SearchResults}>
    {results[element]}    
  </div>);
}
```

Or use an implicit return from the arrow function by using parentheses `()` around it to have the whole function be just one statement (instead of an explicit function body):

```
(
  <div className={classes.SearchResults}>
    {results[element]}    
  </div>
)
```

---

**Additionally...** The use of `results[element]` looks wrong here.  The first callback argument to `.map()` isn't the *index*, it's the element itself.  I suspect you want this:

```
(
  <div className={classes.SearchResults}>
    {element}    
  </div>
)
```

---

As a final note, in React you'll see warnings if you iterate over an array like this to produce JSX but don't supply a `key` property to the JSX element.  If the `element` object has an identifier, such as an `id` property, you can use that:

```
(
  <div key={element.id} className={classes.SearchResults}>
    {element}    
  </div>
)
```

But failing that, you can always rely on the second argument to the `.map()` callback, which **is** just the array element's index:

```
{results.map((element, i) => (
  <div key={i} className={classes.SearchResults}>
    {element}    
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: This completely solved my issue. Very in-depth and easily understandable. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` just runs your callback ignoring the return value

`map` is used to transform and return a new value for each iteration, hence you can use the following instead:

```
{results.map((element, index) => {
   return (
      <div className={classes.SearchResults} key={index}>
          {results[element]}    
      </div>
   )
})}
```